# GET query not updating placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

I'm using Flot Charts and I want to update a chart. The code to call the script from an "external" html file is:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("plotterfunction", function(var1, var2, var3){
       $("#result").html(var1, var2, var3);
        })
    }, 5000);
```

What this does is to access to plotterfunction.html and then in a span with the id "result", obtain the placeholders from this html and "insert" them in the html that calls it. It works the first time but from this moment on, the charts won't update. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I guess the problem are the variables. I get them in this file but I guess they are the same at each iteration... Would something like this setInterval function work for a variable obtention?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use a `get` function.

You're returning 3 variables which that should be only 1.

Your code should look like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
   $.get("plotterfunction.html", function(var){
       $("#result").html(var);
   })
}, 5000);
```

Comment: But if I need 3 variables in the external html, I'd need to send them all, isn't it like that?

Comment: @jquery_stack Can't think of a way where html would return 3 variables. Maybe you want to get different contents inside 3 container elements? If that's the case let me know.